# Web scraping with BeautifulSoup returns NoneType

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a website with BeautifulSoup and have written the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://gematsu.com/tag/media-create-sales")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

try:
    content = soup.find('div', id='main')
    print (content)
except:
    print ("Exception")
```

However, this returns a NoneType, even though the div exists with the correct ID on the website. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

I'm seeing the div with the id main on the page:

[image]

I also find the div main when I print `soup`:

[image]

Comment: Try to print the variable `soup` and search for the div you wanted in it... probably you won't find it. If that's the case, that's because the page's content is dynamically generated... Try using `selenium`

Comment: If I print `soup` I can see the div with main.

Comment: I've tried it myself... I couldn't find `<div id="main"`... Try it again, please!!

Comment: @Anwarvic Open devtools in chrome, use the xpath search tool, `//div[@id="main"]`

Comment: To the close voters, I'm about to replicate the OPs issue. @Fang it seems `html.parser` is stripping out the `id` attribute for that tag. Changing `html.parser` to `lxml` or `html5lib` works for me

Comment: @Wondercricket That definitely worked! Thank you. Do you have an explanation and would you mind putting that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is briefly covered in [BeautifulSoup's documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers)

> Beautiful Soup presents the same interface to a number of different parsers, but each parser is different. Different parsers will create different parse trees from the same document. The biggest differences are between the HTML parsers and the XML parsers
>
> [ ... ]
>
> Here’s the same document parsed with Python’s built-in HTML parser:
>
> `BeautifulSoup("<a></p>", "html.parser")`
>
> Like html5lib, this parser ignores the closing `</p>` tag. Unlike html5lib, this parser makes no attempt to create a well-formed HTML document by adding a  tag. Unlike lxml, it doesn’t even bother to add an  tag.

The issue you are experiencing is likely due to malformed HTML that `html.parser` is not able to handle appropriately. This resulted in `id="main"` being stripped when BeautifulSoup parsed the HTML. By changing the parser to either `html5lib` or `lxml`, BeautifulSoup handles malformed HTML differently than `html.parser`